# Can't get my Facebook messenger bot to respond with response from my service

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I have made an Api.Ai bot and integrated it with both Slack and Facebook Messenger. When I write to it, it answers with the responses set up in Api.Ai for both Slack and Facebook Messenger, but on the fulfillment part, when Api.Ai makes a call to my service, it works fine in Slack, but I get no response from Facebook Messenger.

The format of the message I return from my service:

```
{
"contextOut": [
    {
        "lifespan": 2,
        "name": "weather",
        "parameters": {
            "city": "Rome"
        }
    }
],
"data": {
    "facebook": {
        "message": {
            "text": "Great success!"
        },
        "recipient": {
            "id": "1454102654663349"
        }
    },
    "slack": {
        "attachments": [
            {
                "color": "#00A399",
                "title": "Hello world!",
                "title_link": "https://www.mywebsite.se"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Horray! Great success! :)"
    }
},
"displayText": "Whatever!!",
"followupEvent": {
    "followupEvent": {
        "data": {
            "parameter": "<parameter_value>"
        },
        "name": "<event_name>"
    }
},
"source": "mywebsite.se",
"speech": "Whatever!?"
}
```

The Facebook recipient id comes from the request made to my service.

```
request.result.contexts[0].parameters.Facebook_sender_id
```

I have verified my webhook under the product settings tab in the Facebook app.
I have subscribed my app to the page using my page access token.
I have checked the following events under webhooks: messages, messaging_postbacks
I'm logged in as the admin user of the app, when trying the bot in Facebook.

I'm out of ideas, there must be something I've missed?

EDIT:
I've set up an Azure Function as my webhook for testing purposes.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var request = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiAiMessage>();

    log.Info($"Incoming: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)}");

    var slack_message = new {
        text = $"Horray! Great success! :)",
        attachments = new[] {
            new {
                    title = "Hello world!",
                    title_link = "https://www.mywebsite.se",
                    color = "#00A399"
                 }
            }
        };

    var facebook_message = new {
            recipient = new {
                id = $"{request.result.contexts[0].parameters.Facebook_sender_id}"
                },
            message = new {
                    text = "Great success!"
                }
            };

    var response = new
    {
        data = new
            {
                facebook = facebook_message,
                slack = slack_message
            },
        speech = "Whatever!?",
        displayText = "Whatever!!",
        contextOut = new[] {
            new {
                    name = "weather",
                    lifespan = 2,
                    parameters = new {
                        city = "Rome"
                    }
                }
            },
        source = "mywebsite.se",
        followupEvent = new {
            followupEvent = new {
                name = "<event_name>",
                data = new {
                    parameter = "<parameter_value>"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    log.Info($"Outgoing: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)}");

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

Comment: How are you actually making the request to Facebook with the API.ai response? The above code isn't super helpful for diagnosing the problem if the problem is that your are using some un-pasted code to send the response to FB and that's where the break is occurring.

Also, have you tested in Postman? Are you sure you are sending the request with the right FB page token and parameters?

Comment: Sending the request with Postman works fine, and the same with Slack. Bot yields the response pasted in my question. I log the outgoing message in my service and can see that the response is the same when sending the request from Facebook Messenger. The only difference being the facebook recipient id is obviously not there when doing the request from other sources than Facebook.
I've edited my question with the Azure Function I'm using.

Comment: Where are you sending the FB token back to messenger?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you actually sending the API.ai response back to Facebook Messenger? This requires some FB specifics like the 'page token' and the fact it works for Slack but not FB makes me believe it's just something simple left out like this. Here's an example in javascript of what the call would look like

```js
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
 request({
  uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
  qs: {
   access_token: config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN
  },
  method: 'POST',
  json: messageData

 }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
   var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
   var messageId = body.message_id;

   if (messageId) {
    console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s",
     messageId, recipientId);
   } else {
    console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s",
     recipientId);
   }
  } else {
   console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: That's the format to make a POST to the Facebook API. My issue was about receiving a post from Facebook API, via API.AI, to my service, and forming the correct response. Sorry if I was unclear about that.